# Gremlins.js: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, fuzz-testing, gremlinjs

I'm attempting to inject the following gremlins.js code into my webpage with the command line (node):

> javascript:(function(){function callback(){gremlins.createHorde().unleash()} var s=document.createElement("script");s.src="https://rawgithub.com/marmelab/gremlins.js/master/gremlins.min.js";if(s.addEventListener){s.addEventListener("load",callback,false)}else if(s.readyState){s.onreadystatechange=callback}document.body.appendChild(s);})()

but I keep getting the `ReferenceError: document is not defined` error, and I haven't been able to find anything yet that fixes it. 
I am relatively new to javascript. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You want to inject this code from node side to client side?

Comment: I think so? (I'm relatively new). I'm running a NightWatch test, and I'm trying to use a command to 'Run a JavaScript script in the current browser context.' I don't know if this helps, but it's what I know.